# Problem using async/await function with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

Good Morning,

Even after reading about the concepts and uses of `async` and `await`, i'm still having problems with real aplicattions of them.

Basically in my `ngOnInit` I do a call to a function:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authenticateUser();
  }
```

Function that is:

```
authenticateUser() {

    console.log("----Autenticando Usuário----");

    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    this.userPhoto = localStorage.getItem("userPhoto");

    this.currentUser = this.auth.getSession(this.token);

    this.attributions = this.currentUser.sessao.grupos;
    this.userEmail = this.currentUser.sessao.email;
    this.instalation = this.currentUser.instalacao;

   }
```

The problem is that `currentUser` value returns as `null` in its execution, because its value was setted before the return from the promise in `this.auth.getSession(this.token);`

This `Auth` is constructed in a service called `RestApiService`

```
constructor(private auth: RestApiService) { }
```

Also I have inside that service the method `getSession()` that returns a `JSON`with user informations from the `API`

```
getSession(xtrToken) {
    xtrToken = "{\"token\":\"" + xtrToken.toString() + "\"}";
    this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/auth", xtrToken)
      .subscribe(function (resposta) {
        if (resposta != null) {
          localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(resposta));
          if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            var url = window.location.href;
            var value = url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf('?'));
            value = value.replace('@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]', '');
            var newUrl = value;
            window.history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
          }
          this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        }
      });
      return this.currentUser;
  }
```

I've tried putting `getSession` as `async`, and in its call, something like this:

```
async authenticateUser() {

    console.log("----Autenticando Usuário----");

    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    this.userPhoto = localStorage.getItem("userPhoto");

    this.currentUser = await this.auth.getSession(this.token);

    this.attributions = this.currentUser.sessao.grupos;
    this.userEmail = this.currentUser.sessao.email;
    this.instalation = this.currentUser.instalacao;

   }
```

But it didn't make any difference.

So, is there a way to wait the result from the `API` before I set the value in `this.currentUser` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Already tried that solution, didn't work tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your `getSession` method tries to perform an asynchronous action, you haven't set it up to do so properly. You're returning `currentUser` outside of the `subscribe` block, and the whole method has no way of telling its caller that it is asynchronous, so async/await won't make a difference.

When it comes to async methods, you have a few choices. In Angular, we generally use Observables as they allow the most control. In this case, you could simply return the `http.post` Observable in `getSession`, and then subscribe to it in `authenticateUser`. Then you can either put the following lines inside the `subscribe` call *or* use `pipe` and RxJS operators to perform the next actions.

You could also have `getSession` return a `Promise` which resolves with the required data. That would allow async/await to work (although it's not an Angular pattern).

Comment: When I try to subscribe to it at the `authenticateUser` it only appears to unsubscribe, do you know why would that happen?

Comment: Because you're returning the `Subscription` because you've left the `subscribe` call in `getSession`  Like I said, you take the `subscribe` call out of `getSession` and place it in `authenticateUser`.

Answer (score 0):

getSession() must return a promise in order for await to work in this case.

```
return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/auth", xtrToken)
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

or

```
getSession(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...
        resolve(data)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe with map from rxjs to your return value and set to JSON. Promise and Observable are slight different even though both are asynchronous operation. When you use observable pattern and it stared listening to it when you subscribe which means you may receive multiple values later (async). Promise pattern gives you back one value later which you will listen to from resolve(result).

```
login(model: AccessUser) {
    return this.http.post(this.endpoint, model).pipe(
      map((response: AccessToken) => {
        const user = response;
        if (user) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
          localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.user));
          this.decodedToken = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(user.token);
          this.currentUser = user.user;
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

So in your case,

```
getSession(xtrToken) {
    xtrToken = "{\"token\":\"" + xtrToken.toString() + "\"}";
    this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/auth", xtrToken)
      .map((resposta) => {
        if (resposta != null) {
          localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(resposta));
          if (window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
            var url = window.location.href;
            var value = url = url.slice(0, url.indexOf('?'));
            value = value.replace('@System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"]', '');
            var newUrl = value;
            window.history.pushState({}, null, newUrl);
          }
          this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        }
      });
      return this.currentUser;
  }

authenticateUser() {

    console.log("----Autenticando Usuário----");

    this.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    this.userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    this.userPhoto = localStorage.getItem("userPhoto");

    this.auth.getSession(this.token).subscribe((result) => {
    this.currentUser = result;
    });

    this.attributions = this.currentUser.sessao.grupos;
    this.userEmail = this.currentUser.sessao.email;
    this.instalation = this.currentUser.instalacao;

   }
```

Comment: put the lineas of this.attributions=this.currentUser,this.userEmail.. INSIDE subscribe function